# How to make Hangouts automatically fallback to sms when no data connection?

Tags: sms, settings, data-connection, google-hangouts

I use the latest Hangouts version (the one rolled out a few days ago, which now supports voice calls) on a Nexus 5. I have set Hangouts as my default messaging app. In the past the following behavior was possible: when I was sending a message to a contact on Hangouts, if either I or they didn't have an internet connection, Hangouts would automatically send it as sms. Now it doesn't behave like this. 
Currently, if the sender has no internet it would show status `sending` under the text of the message forever. But if the receiver has no internet, it would show the message as `sent` on the device of the sender, giving you no clue, that the other party hasn't actually received the message. Is there a way to revert to the old behavior (similar to iMessage on iPhone) - if any of the two doesn't have an internet connection - use sms?

Comment: I suspect [this](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2449821/sms-for-google-hangouts-discontinued-but-its-not-what-you-think.html) might be the cause of the problem, but hope there is still a workaround.